# Deleting output (subset) from main dataset in SAS

Tags: sas, subset, delete-row

I want to delete the subsets (I am creating if-then output statement) from main dataset in SAS. In the below example in the next step I would like to delete entries/ rows in subsets a b and c from dataset z. Please share your ideas.

```
data a b c;
      set z;
      if find(scan(name,1,' '),',') and find(name,' MD ') then output a;
      else if find(scan(name,1,' '),',') and not find(name,' MD ') then output b;
      else if count(strip(name),' ')=2 and length(compress(scan(name,2,' '),'.'))=1 then output c;
run;
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First off, if this is your real program, then you should simply output to a new-z in the same data step.

```
data a b c z_new; 
  set z;
  if ... then output a;
  else if ... then output b;
  else if ... then output c;
  else output z_new;
run;
```

However, if this is artificial for the question and a/b/c are created elsewhere, you have a number of options, that mostly depend on the size of the data - how efficient this needs to be, and other details that determine what 'efficient' and 'possible' means.

The most straightforward, though, is the merge:

```
data z_new;
  merge z(in=_z) a(in=_a) b(in=_b) c(in=_c);
  by name;
  if _z and not (_a or _b or _c);
run;
```

This keeps only records that are in z and not in a, b, or c.  This assumes `name` is the unique identifier - if it isn't, use whatever is the unique identifier as the `by` variable.